# Creating an RSS test feed, the manual points me to non existing menu option?

Tags: facebook, rss

This is my first post so please be gentle.

This manual from Facebook, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/publishing/setup-rss-feed, says; ' From the top of your Page, click Publishing Tools, then select **Configuration** under the **Instant Articles** header from the menu on the left of the screen. Under the Tools section, choose Production RSS Feed.'

So, I was able to click 'Publishing Tools', and then I get on the left, only these options;

Posts

Videos

Video Library

Videos You Can Crosspost

Sounds

Sound Collection

Branded Content

Posts to Review

Your Posts

Lead Ads Forms

Forms Library

Draft Forms Library

Canvas

I have no **Configuration** or **Instant Articles** shown. *How do I overcome this?* I really would like to find the 'Tools section which should contain '**Production RSS Feed**'

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/guides/publishertools: _“You will not be able to access the publishing tools until you have completed signup and designated a Facebook Page to use for Instant Articles.”_ ... have you done that?

Comment: I wasn't aware of that part of manual that contains a link for signup. It is saying to click on 'Instant Articles', as shown in their picture which I have added here. [picture from Facebook manual][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tggPX.png

While 'Instant Articles' is clearly shown, on my Facbook it goes from 'Lead Ad Forms' to 'Canvas'.

The 'Instant Articles' menu option just isn't their either. I hope someone can tell me how to open that menu option? [picture from current Facebook page][2]


  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruPaC.png

Comment: I've found a workaround, hootsuite.com connects a RSS feed to a Facebook page and it is working well for some time now.